# Position a Window On Screen

Tags: jquery, resize, window, position

Is there a way to position a window opened with jQuery to the top right corner of the screen?

This is the code I have right now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dirs a").click(function() {
        // opens in new window
        window.open(this.href, "customWindow", "width=960, height=1040");
        return false;
    });
});
```

And I want it to open in the top right corner of the screen, similar to how it would appear if "snapped" with Windows Aero snap in Vista or higher. Is there a way to make this happen?

By the way, this is a simple page that only I will use, and I will only use it in Chrome on a 1920x1080 monitor, so it doesn't have to have any fancy stuff to adjust for different browsers or screen sizes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If he wants it on the top right doesn't he need this?

```
window.open(this.href, "customWindow", "width=960, height=1040, top=0, left=960");
```

Comment: Oh dang, just adding that left=960 fixed it. Thanks, that's perfect :)

Comment: Sorry top should be 0, not 40! Fixed it

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript window.open accepts lots of parameters. To your particular case, top and left should suffice.

See the working [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/jB6AY/)

**The Syntax**

```
window.open([URL], [Window Name], [Feature List], [Replace]);
```

**The Feature list**

[image]

**The working example to fit your needs**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popup(url) 
{
 var width  = 960;
 var height = 1040;
 var left   = screen.width - 960;
 var top    = 0;
 var params = 'width='+width+', height='+height;
 params += ', top='+top+', left='+left;
 params += ', directories=no';
 params += ', location=no';
 params += ', menubar=no';
 params += ', resizable=no';
 params += ', scrollbars=no';
 params += ', status=no';
 params += ', toolbar=no';
 newwin=window.open(url,'customWindow', params);
 if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
 return false;
}
// -->
</script>

<a href="javascript: void(0)" 
   onclick="popup('popup.html')">Top Right popup window</a>
```

**Note:**
This will calculate the screen width to set the `left` properly.

*Take into consideration that you are using a window with a large height, usually, screens are larger than taller...*

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dirs a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var popupWidth = 960;
    var leftPos = screen.width - popupWidth;

    window.open(this.href, "customWindow", "width=" + popupWidth + ", height=1040, top=0, left=" + leftPos);
});
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MpjMX/1/).

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open(this.href, "customWindow", "width=960, height=1040, top=0, left=0");
```

Other window properties:

```
Property         Default value   Description
width            auto            specifies width of the new window in pixels
height           auto            height of the window in pixels
top              auto            specifies window position
left             auto            specifies window position
directories      no              should the directories bar be shown? (Links bar)
location         no              specifies the presence of the location bar
resizable        no              specifies whether the window can be resized.
menubar          no              specifies the presence of the menu bar
toolbar          no              specifies the presence of the toolbar
scrollbars       no              specifies the presence of the scrollbars
status           no              specifies the presence of the statusbar
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work, at least not in Chrome. EDIT: Works fine in Firefox. Maybe I'll just use that if I don't get a better answer.

Comment: @Marko - really?! - there is only one correct answer and we posted at the same time

Answer (score 1):

This is the right one.. You need to calculate the width of the screen first.

```
var leftPos = screen.width - 960;
window.open(this.href, "customWindow", "width=960, height=1040, top=40, left="+leftPos+");
```

Comment: "this is a simple page that only I will use, and I will only use it in Chrome on a 1920x1080 monitor"